# How do I do this math right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(2 + 3x) * (4 + 5x) = 2(4 + 5x) + 3x(4 + 5x)$

I don't get it. What do I do?

Comment: This is a consequence of the distributive property of arithmetic operations: $(a+b)\cdot c = a\cdot c + b \cdot c$.

Comment: Suppose you put $x = 10$ so that the sum becomes $32 \times 54$. I hope you can see that you can compute this by splitting it up as $30 \times 54 + 2 \times 54$ - with a little jiggling of the order of terms you get the same pattern as you have stated. This is an example of the distributive law, and putting $x$ instead of $10$ generalises from the case of numbers in the decimal system to a wide range of applications.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you asking if what you wrote is correct (it is, as others have already explained), or how to proceed further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation you have uses the law of distribution:
$$a(b+c)= ab + ac$$
If you set $a=4+5x$, $b=2$ and $c=3x$, you get the equation in your question.